# Fiiltering select box content using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to filter the content of one select box using option selected in another select box. Here is my code:

```
 //filter content according to the selected option on a select box on a
 //page  
 //Get the value of the option selectd in region box    
 var $selectedRegion = $('#region');

  // fire function when region value changed 
 $selectedRegion.change(function(){

  //cycle through each element of data and get its value  

  $('select#data').find('option').each(function() {

  //Get the value of the option selected in data box

  var $item = $(this).val();

      //check if the value of data and region is same. If not hide the data name                    

 if($selectedRegion.val() !== $item ) {
       $(this).wrap('<span>').hide();    }
     });    });'
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="inline-select-boxes">
   <label for="data" class="inline-block"><legend><span class="number">1</span> Select Region</legend></label>
    <select id="region" name="region" class="padded region">
      <option value="select-one" id="select-one">Select one</option>
        <option value="north" id="north">North</option>
        <option value="south">South </option>
        <option value="east">East</option>
        <option value="west">West</option>

     </select>
   </div>

   <div class="inline-select-boxes">
   <label for="data" class="inline-block"><legend><span class="number">2</span> Select item</legend></label>
    <select id="data" name="data" class="padded ">
        <option value="select one">Select one</option>
        <option value="north">i1</option>
        <option value="north">i2 </option>
        <option value="south">i3 </option>
        <option value="east">i4 </option>
     </select>
```

However this works only once. For ex. if i select north from the first box, the second box displays "i1" and "i2" and hides the rest. But when i select the second option(ex. south), the relevant options('i3') don't appear. they remain hidden. What can i do to reset the content of second box so that the relevant content on selecting the second box appears as well.

Comment: on every change show all the options before filter

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to take the binding out of the markup and create map of what you want to show in your script. Consider the following snippet;

```js
(function () {
  var CLASSES = {
    region    : '.select__region',
    data      : '.select__data'
  },
    map = {
      NORTH: [
        'i1',
        'i2'
      ],
      SOUTH: [
        'i3'
      ],
      EAST: [
        'i4'
      ],
      WEST: [
        
      ]
    },
    regionSelect = document.querySelector(CLASSES.region),
    dataSelect     = document.querySelector(CLASSES.data),
    filterData = function(val) {
      var opts = dataSelect.options,
        allowedOpts = map[val];
      dataSelect.value = allowedOpts[0];
      for(var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
        if (allowedOpts.indexOf(opts[i].value) === -1) {
          opts[i].hidden = true;
        } else {
          opts[i].hidden = false;
        }     
      }
    };


  filterData(regionSelect.value);

  regionSelect.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    filterData(this.value);
  });

}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <select id="region" class="select__region">
    <option value="NORTH">North</option>
    <option value="SOUTH">South</option>
    <option value="EAST">East</option>
    <option value="WEST">West</option>
  </select>
  <select id="data" class="select__data">
    <option value="i1">i1</option>
    <option value="i2">i2</option>
    <option value="i3">i3</option>
    <option value="i4">i4</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

This will do what you intend but without the coupled select markup. You can also see this available in a jsBin [here](http://jsbin.com/naqugatayo/edit?html,js,console,output).

Alternatively, to do it with your original style markup like this (also available on [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/doqacukoro/1/edit?html,js,console,output));

```js
(function () {
  var CLASSES = {
    region    : '.select__region',
    data      : '.select__data'
  },
    regionSelect = document.querySelector(CLASSES.region),
    dataSelect     = document.querySelector(CLASSES.data),
    filterData = function(val) {
      var opts = dataSelect.options;
      dataSelect.value = val;
      for(var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
        if (opts[i].value === val) {
          opts[i].hidden = false;
        } else {
          opts[i].hidden = true;
        }     
      }
    };


  filterData(regionSelect.value);

  regionSelect.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    filterData(this.value);
  });
  
  dataSelect.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    console.log(this.value);
  });

}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <select id="region" class="select__region">
    <option value="NORTH">North</option>
    <option value="SOUTH">South</option>
    <option value="EAST">East</option>
    <option value="WEST">West</option>
  </select>
  <select id="data" class="select__data">
    <option value="NORTH">i1</option>
    <option value="NORTH">i2</option>
    <option value="SOUTH">i3</option>
    <option value="EAST">i4</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

However, the latter solution makes it less convenient to extract the selected value for the data select so the map solution would make things easier for you I believe.

Hope that helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your JS with this one. It will work for you. Thanks

```
$selectedRegion = $('#region');
$selectedRegion.change(function(){
  var $item = $(this).val();
  $("#data option[value!="+$item+"]").hide();
  $("#data option[value="+$item+"]").show();
});
```

You can check output here https://jsfiddle.net/prakashlaxkar/bv5jfr8n/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It did work. But there is one problem. It stops working when i add the 'select2' plugin to the search box. I could not figure out a solution to that.